# Web Form not showing properly inside iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to show the map in asp.net web application with master page.
   Master page have form tag so that create new form with map and create another 
   form with master page and iframe control. In that control show the web form.

**My Code :**

```
<asp:Content ID="cntNavigation" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntMain" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calcHeight(iframeElement) {
            var the_height = iframeElement.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
            iframeElement.height = the_height;
        }
</script>
   <iframe id="myIframe" src="Tracking.aspx" onload="calcHeight(this)" scrolling="no" style="position:relative;left:0px;width:100%;top:0px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;border:none; " ></iframe>
</asp:Content>
```

In that "Tracking" form create with bootstrap text box and map but its not showing properly in application

**Tracking Form Code :**

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
                <strong class="card-title">SalesMan Live Tracking</strong>
        </div>
        <div id="divstrackingbody" class="card-body">
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <label class="col-form-label">Start</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <input type="text" name="start" id="start"  class="form-control"/>   
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <label class="col-form-label">End</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                 <input type="text" name="end" id="end" class="form-control"  />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();"  class="btn btn-success"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mapbody" class="card-body">
             <div id="map_canvas" class="map"></div>
        </div>

  </div>
```

**Expected :**

```
                ________________               ________________
   Start     : +___textbox______+     End   : +____textbox_____+
```

Showing :

```
   Start  :
   -----------------------------------------------------------
   +            textbox                                      +
   -----------------------------------------------------------

  End:
   -----------------------------------------------------------
   +          textbox                                       +
   -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How is not displaying properly? How do you expect it to display?

Comment: @ZimSystem Kindly check it now

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap 4**, `.col-` that are *not* placed in `.row`s **they will wrap/stack vertically**.

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and ***only***
>   columns may be ***immediate children of rows***.

So, if you don't want the columns to wrap/stack, they must be contained in a `.row` ...

https://www.codeply.com/go/khfnoOSDMU

```
 <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
                <strong class="card-title">SalesMan Live Tracking</strong>
        </div>
        <div id="divstrackingbody" class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <label class="col-form-label">Start</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <input type="text" name="start" id="start" class="form-control">   
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <label class="col-form-label">End</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                 <input type="text" name="end" id="end" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-top:2%;">
                <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mapbody" class="card-body">
             <div id="map_canvas" class="map"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time but its not working for me